# paperclip detect p8 files with wrong content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, content-type

I am using paperclip gem in my rails app and I added validation for content type for .p8 file but I found out that `paperclip` detect any p8 file with content type `text/plain`

while I am expecting the content type of p8 files to be `application/pkcs8` or `application/x-pkcs8` any suggestion how can I overcome this problem